# In general, are research articles entirely written by the PhD student?

Tags: publications, phd, writing, supervision

I'm thinking of pursuing a PhD (in France) and I would like to know if the process of writing is merely done by the PhD candidate, or it is helped by their advisor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, the process varies too widely to say yes or no. Some advisors do more with and for the student than others. It can actually be anything from a completely individual effort to a team effort (such as in Big-Science).

The purpose of the advisor is to guide. And even when the student develops the work on their own, the advisor will nearly always provide advice, and even the research question.

But it isn't just that you show up and are told "write a paper". The purpose of the PhD itself is to train a person in the research process, including publishable results in some field.

If it were general practice that the student was expected to do it "on their own" then there would be no reason for the PhD. A publication record would be all that is needed to start a career.

However, some advisors are more "helpful" than others and some students require more "help" than others. If you are mismatched with your advisor it can be frustrating. There are many questions on this site that indicate what can go wrong, usually when an advisor won't or can't provide proper guidance.

When you start the PhD studies your first task is to try to match with a compatible advisor who can and will provide the necessary level of assistance and guidance, whatever that might be for you.

Comment: +1 some students require more "help" than others

Comment: "When you start the PhD studies your first task is to try to match with a compatible advisor": Not sure this is true in France, which, I think, has the typical european system that you find an advisor and *then* you start with your PhD.

Comment: @user151413, but it is good if you can learn something about them before you make a choice. But yes, it is much easier in US. A random choice can turn out poorly.

Comment: ... can turn out poorly for both sides, in fact. In that respect, the US system has clear advantages indeed. (Conversely, people in some places in Europe to quite extensive master's theses, which can also help quite a bit in judging them, at least scientifically. I have a hard time judging applicants from places without a master's thesis, or just a super-short one.)

Comment: At least in the UK it's common (in physics) to start your PhD and then get assigned to an advisor. Only sometimes when students come with a grant that is tied to a specific project the advisor will be known in advance. So your experience with "typical European" will vary. The best bet is always to find advanced PhD students at the place you are applying to and ask them.